# Need help structuring a Django Database with many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I am setting up a Django Model/Database for an app that is designed to track the usage of a `keyword` assigned by a `user` on social media.  Contextual information such as the `message`, `date`, `url`, and `platform` need to be stored for each usage of the `keyword`.

This part is easy enough to accomplish with three models - a `User` model that contains username, first, last, email, and password and a `Keyword` model that contains username as a Foreign Key, and a list of the users' keywords.  A third model `Context` would then be linked via the keyword and contain the contextual information for the usage of the keyword.

So the relationships would look like:

```
User         Keywords         Context
username---->username
             keyword---------->Keyword
             kw_createdate     message
                               post_date
                               url
                               platform
```

However, I also want to enter a number of `RelatedTerms` for each keyword, so for example, if you were tracking the keyword 'python' you could add related terms 'java', 'ruby', and 'c#'.  For the related terms all I really need is a count of the number of times they were used in a given time range, but am not against saving their contextual information as it may be useful in the future.

What I can't figure out is how I should structure the model(s) for storing related terms.  Should I store them in the `Keywords` model and have a flag for primary/related and then also have those words in the context model?

Also, what is the relationship type between keyword as used in the Keywords and Context models?  Two users can have the same keywords, but they will be tracked over different time frames.

Comment: Are related keywords specific to the original keyword only, or to both the original keyword and the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about another model `RelatedKeywords`?

Assuming related keywords are user-specific, this would look something like:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...

class UserKeyword(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='keywords')
    keyword = models.CharField(...)

class UserKewordContext(models.Model):
    user_keyword = models.OneToOneField(UserKeyword, related_name='context')  # Assumes that each UserKeyword can only have one context; change to ForeignKey if that is not the case
    keyword = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class UserRelatedKeyword(models.Model):
    user_keyword = models.ForeignKey(UserKeyword, related_name='related_keywords')
    related_keyword = models.CharField(...)
```

If you have a global `Keyword` store; replace all the keyword storage fields defined as `CharField` to a `ForeignKey`:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class UserKeyword(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='keywords')
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keyword)

class UserKewordContext(models.Model):
    user_keyword = models.OneToOneField(UserKeyword, related_name='context')  # Assumes that each UserKeyword can only have one context; change to ForeignKey if that is not the case
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keyword)
    ...

class UserRelatedKeyword(models.Model):
    user_keyword = models.ForeignKey(UserKeyword, related_name='related_keywords')
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keyword)
```

You can then access the following as follows:

- All the keywords for a given user: `user.keywords.all()`
- The context for each `UserKeyword`: `user_keyword.context`
- All the related keywords for each `UserKeyword`: `user_keyword.related_keywords.all()`